# How should I remove objects from a list when a cancel dialog result is returned?

Tags: c#, list, generics

I am writing a C# forms application where I have many `List<T>` lists. I have many forms that can add and remove objects from these lists. If a users presses the cancel button, and the dialog result is returned as cancel, how is the best way to remove the data that is added to the lists from the form?

Should I take a 'snapshot' of all the lists beforehand, and then restore the lists, or is there a better approach?

All the lists inherit from a ICustomObject interface, and these lists are all stored in one place. They are not specific to each form, but each form can only add and edit items in certain lists.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have specific lists for each form?Or are you using the same across the forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably create a backup of all lists and revert all changes if user press cancel.

```
var list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3};
var list2 = new List<string>() { "Abc", "Def", "Ghi"};

object[] tempData = new[] { list1.ToList(), list2.ToList() };

//... user changes something in list1, list2 ...
list1.Add(12); list1.Remove(3);
list2.Remove("Def");

if(cancel)
{
   list1 = tempData[0] as List<int>;
   list2 = tempData[1] as List<string>; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the approach that I am now using.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `List<T>` directly, you could think of creating a derived class which has sort of transaction logic, so you can `Commit` or `Rollback` the changes. Something like this:

```
public TransactionList<T> : List<T> {
    private List<T> changesList;

    public void AddItem(T item) {
        changesList.Add(item);
    }

    public void Commit() {
        base.AddRange(changesList);
        changesList.Clear();
    }
    public void Rollback() {
        changesList.Clear();
    }        
}
```

Of course, you'd need to add further implementations for modifying or deleting list items, if required. This code is just an example how you could do it for the adding-objects case.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend deriving from `List<T>` here, I'd prefer composition.  To me, the transaction behavior is something that applies to an already existing list, it doesn't represent a special kind of list behavior.  It also isn't modifying the list behavior in any way, it's just adding additional functionality.